# Yang-Mills self-energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, yang-mills, self-energy

I am trying to write the diagrams associated with the self energy of a Yang-Mills field.
I have already computed the Feynman rules for the propagators and for a vertice of: 3 gluons; 4 gluons; 2 ghosts and a gluon.
I have considered the following diagrams:

[image]

I don't know for sure if the following terms are also considered for the self energy:

[image]

Are there other diagrams?
(If anyone could recommend a book where I could read more about this, it would also be nice)

Comment: If you allow an unlimited number of loops, there are an *infinite* number of diagrams. Typically you compute to one-loop order, or two-loop order, or whatever you can manage. At each order the number of diagrams is finite.

Comment: @G.Smith I understand that. Should I work them out up to some order? Can I generalize the full sum in some way?

Comment: I don’t think you can generalize the full sum. If you are planning to actually calculate them, I think the integrals are relatively easy when they have one loop but much harder when they have two or more. I personally have never calculated a Feynman diagram with more than one loop, so there might be techniques I don’t know about. If all you care about is enumerating the diagrams, then it doesn’t matter how hard they are to evaluate.

Comment: @G.Smith There are some techniques used by people working in amplitudes which involve finding a basis of integrals needed to write all diagrams as linear combinations of those basic integrals. However, I think it's also worth mentioning that if this calculation is in QCD then I think the weak coupling assumption fails, which is why lattice QCD is such a large area of study. As G. Smith states though, if you're only interested in writing the possible diagrams and not evaluating, none of my above comments matter.